# Printing a List with Newlines in TKinter Popup

Tags: python, string, list, tkinter

I've got this list:

```
runner.sublist = [["one","two","three"],["red","black","blue]]
```

and this class definition

```
class popupWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, master, txt):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(master)
        self.l = Label(top, text=txt)
        self.l.pack()
        self.b = Button(top, text='Fine....', command=self.cleanup)
        self.b.pack()

def popup(self,txt):
    self.w=popupWindow(self.master, txt)
    self.master.wait_window(self.w.top)
```

And I'm trying to get this button to make a popup window that has the `runner.sublist` list printed in the popup with newlines after every group of elements (one two three on the first line, red black blue on the second, etc.)

```
def print_it(op):
    out = '\n'.join(op)
    return out


class mainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.b2=Button(master,text="print value",command=lambda: self.popup(print_it(runner.sublist)))
        self.b2.pack()
```

However, this code returns the following error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found
```

Clearly, I'm passing a list where I should have a string, but I'm totally stumped as to why it's getting a list!  I've tried to coerce some of the values into strings at various places, but that had no luck.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` can joins `list of strings` but not `list of lists of strings`.

(see: `lambda: self.popup(print_it(runner.sublist))` )

```
'\n'.join( [["one","two","three"],["red","black","blue"]] ) # error
```

You have to change `print_it()`. For example:

```
def print_it(op):
    return '\n'.join( ' '.join(line) for line in op )
```

To get two lines

```
one two three
red black blue
```